# Sql query for adding dates in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a tables named as deep_test in which there are column A,B,C and D. column A is primary key and B,C are date datatype columns and D is foreign key from other table.

requirement :-
I need to add all dates which are lying between +16 days of column C and -16 days of column B.

For example, now i have data like this in my table.

```
A    B             C              D
------------------------------------
1    20.04.2014    21.04.2014     40
2    22.04.2014    22.04.2014     40
3    06.05.2014    10.05.2014     40
4    15.05.2014    30.05.2014     40
5    01.01.2014    10.01.2014     41
6    11.01.2014    25.01.2014     41
7    01.02.2014    10.02.2014     41
8    15.02.2014    20.02.2014     41
9    25.02.2014    26.02.2014     41
```

If you check +16 days of C column and -16 days of B column if any dates lies with in this range it should clubbed against column D which is foreign key and show me the below output.

I am using oracle 11i database.

output as :-

```
B            C           D
---------------------------
20.04.2014   30.05.2014  40
01.01.2014   26.02.2014  41
```

Query I am using is :-

```
SELECT X.* 
  FROM dummy X
 WHERE ( X.date_end BETWEEN (X.date_start - 16)
                        AND X.date_start
         OR date_start BETWEEN X.date_end
                           AND (X.date_end + 16) ) 
 GROUP BY X.D;
```

But it is not giving me exact output.

Comment: Can you post your question more clearer? +16 days from which date? Atleast provide the entire expected output in your sample data.

Comment: "clubbed against column D"? I only club baby seals. Do you mean `grouped by`? And you are saying "check +16 days of C" - but check it against what value? "If any dates" if any of which dates? Your question is difficult to understand, so it is difficult to provide help.

Comment: here is explanation for for first row in my output.if you see the dats in table with C=40 then you will have first four rows...so now with this you need to check whether the dats are lying in +16 and -16 range of column B and column C.so take first row with dates 20.04.2014 -21.04.2014 now check 21.04.2014+16 days and 20.04.2014-16 days if this is true then my min and max dats keeps on changes untill it condition get satisfied.so that's why in my output you will find only only one row with all dates for c=40.

Comment: take each and every row and check condition of +/-16 logic with the dates if this keep on satisfying.if you see all the dates with c=40&c=41 are lying with in 16 days so thts the output is all about....hope this is much clear.i found this difficult with sql but can do it with plsql block also....but i need to know is there is any way with oracle sql also??

Answer (score 0):

Guessing:

```
select min(B), max(C), D
from T
group by D
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all adjacent date ranges where gaps up to 16 days are allowed.

Here is how to: Order the records by D and B and for every record look into the previous record if we are in an adjacent date range (with LAG). Mark every group change with a 1 (with CASE). Then go through the records again and have a running total of group changes (with SUM OVER), which gives you group numbers. Then get min start date and max end date per group.

```
B           C           D   group_change  range_group
01.01.2014  02.01.2014  10  1             1
04.01.2014  06.01.2014  10  0             1
31.01.2014  02.01.2014  10  1             2
10.02.2014  14.02.2014  10  0             2
01.01.2014  10.01.2014  20  1             3
20.01.2014  25.01.2014  20  0             3
```

```
B           C           D
01.01.2014  06.01.2014  10
31.01.2014  14.02.2014  10
01.01.2014  25.01.2014  20
```

```
select min(B) as start_date, max(C) as end_date, min(D) as D
from
(
  select B, C, D, sum(group_change) over (order by D, B) as range_group
  from
  (
    select B, C, D, 
      case 
        when B - lag(C) over (partition by D order by B) <= 16 then 0 
        else 1 
      end as group_change
    from mytable
  )
)
group by range_group
order by min(B), D;
```

Here is an SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a1144/10.